# Tools for generating strong passphrases?

Tags: passwords, utility, passphrase

Passphrases seem like a good alternative for traditional
guidelines for strong passwords. See http://xkcd.com/936/ for an entertaining take on passwords vs. passphrases.

There are many tools for generating more traditional passwords (eg. pwgen.)
Such tools are useful when for example providing users with good initial passwords.

What tools are available for generating good passphrases?

Do you have experience on using them or insight about their security or other features?

Comment: There is an excellent discussion on the topic of passphrases and passwords at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase

Comment: Passphrases are good, because the base of possible words is so big `combinations = numberOfPossibleWords ^ numerOfWordsInPhrase`. So every passphrase generator is only as good as the dictionary it can pick words from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a command line based Perl script [passphrase-generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/passphrase-gen/).

The passphrase-generator defaults to only 3 words instead of the 4 suggested by XKCD, but uses a larger dictionary found in many linux based systems at /usr/share/dict/words. It also provides estimates for the entropy of the generated passphrases. The randomization is based on /dev/urandom and SHA1.

Example run:

```
$ passphrase-generator 

Random passphrase generator

Entropy per passphrase is 43.2 bits (per word: 14.4 bits.)

For reference, entropy of completely random 8 character (very hard to memorize)
password of upper and lowercase letters plus numbers is 47.6 bits
Entropy of a typical human generated "strong" 8 character password is in the
ballpark of 20 - 30 bits.

Below is a list of 16 passphrases.
Assuming you select one of these based on some non random preference
your new passphrase will have entropy of 39.2 bits.

Note that first letter is always capitalized and spaces are
replaced with '1' to meet password requirements of many systems.

Goatees1maneuver1pods
Aught1fuel1hungers
Flavor1knock1foreman
Holding1holster1smarts
Vitamin1mislead1abhors
Proverbs1lactose1brat
... and so on 10 more
```

There are also some browser/javascript based tools:

- http://preshing.com/20110811/xkcd-password-generator
- http://passphra.se/
- http://lightsecond.com/passphrase.html

CPAN hosts a Perl module for generating XKCD style passphrases:

- [http://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::XkcdPassword](http://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aXkcdPassword)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently released a couple of Perl scripts, `gen-password` and `gen-passphrase`, on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/random-passwords).

The `gen-passphrase` script could suit your needs. It takes three arguments: a word used as a sequence of initials, a minimum length, and a maximum length. For example:

```
$ gen-passphrase abcde 6 8
acrimony borrowed chasten drifts educable
```

or you can ask for a number of words without specifying their initials (a new feature I just added):

```
$ gen-passphrase 5 6 8
poplin outbreak aconites academic azimuths
```

It requires a word list; it uses `/usr/share/dict/words` by default if it exists. It uses `/dev/urandom` by default, but can be told to use `/dev/random`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/359601/92954) of mine on superuser.com for more information about `/dev/urandom` vs. `/dev/urandom`.

**NOTE:** So far, nobody other than me has tested these scripts. I've made my best effort to have them generate strong passwords/passphrases, but I guarantee nothing.

Comment: Looks good. On a quick reading seems very similar to my script (also written in perl). I asked this question to collect information on all tools in this class in one place. Hopefully one good passphrase generator will end up in OS distributions (alongside with pwgen and other password generators).